# OSX activate PFA/PFB fonts with ATSFontActivateFromMemory

Tags: macos, fonts

I am trying to find a way to activate PC PFA/PFB PostScript font on OS X by code. CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL works only for TTF and OTF, but I was wondering if ATSFontActivateFromMemory could not be used, as it is described as :

> You use this function to activate a streamed font, such as a font contained in a PDF file. Your application must first map the streamed font data to memory and then pass the address of the font data in memory to the function ATSFontActivateFromMemory.

I could load the font data and point to it. So far no joy, but I wonder if someone here would have any pointers.

Comment: ...why? PFA/PFB are an obsolete font format, what on earth are you trying to do with them?

Comment: Customers happen to still have these fonts, and I am looking for a way to activate them. No need to look down on them.

Comment: Actually, every need, they're a remnant of the past and should no longer be used unless you have no choice. Which in this case you don't. Is converting them to modern format first a legally available option?

Comment: It is not always possible to convert fonts when their license term prohibit it. Hence I am looking for a way.